# What caused the different behaviors in partial specialization of non-type template argument?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, partial-specialization

I'm trying to complete a template metaprogramming exercise[text](https://www.slamecka.cz/posts/2021-03-17-cpp-metaprogramming-exercises-1/). However, I meet different behaviors when I' trying to partially specialize an non-type template argument.

I define a compile time vector.

```
template <int... Nums>
struct Vector {};
```

Then, I define a "Get" operation about the "Vector", and the code could be compiled.

```
template <size_t Idx, typename Vec>
struct Get;

template <int Head, int... Tail>
struct Get<0, Vector<Head, Tail...>> // partial specialize the "Idx"
{
    static constexpr int value = Head;
};

template <size_t Idx, int Head, int... Tail>
struct Get<Idx, Vector<Head, Tail...>>
{
    static_assert(Idx > 0, "Out of Vector bound");
    static constexpr int value = Get<Idx - 1, Vector<Tail...>>::value;
};
```

**However, When I trying to define the "Insert" operation like below, the code compilation failed in VS2022 and the error code is "C2752 more than one partial specialization matches".**

```
template <size_t Pos, int Val, typename Vec>
struct Insert;

template <size_t Pos, int Val, typename Vec>
using InsertT = typename Insert<Pos, Val, Vec>::type;

template <int Val, int... Elems>
struct Insert<0, Val, Vector<Elems...>> // partial specialize the "Pos"
{
    using type = Vector<Val, Elems...>;
};

template <size_t Pos, int Val, int Head, int... Tail>
struct Insert<Pos, Val, Vector<Head, Tail...>>
{
    using type = PrependT<Head, InsertT<Pos - 1, Val, Vector<Tail...>>>; // push an element in the front of the vector
};
```

update:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int... Nums>
struct Vector {};

template <int, typename>
struct Prepend;

template <int Ele, typename Vec>
using PrependT = typename Prepend<Ele, Vec>::type;

template <int Ele, int... Nums>
struct Prepend<Ele, Vector<Nums...>>
{
    using type = Vector<Ele, Nums...>;
};

template <size_t Idx, typename Vec>
struct Get;

template <int Head, int... Tail>
struct Get<0, Vector<Head, Tail...>> // partial specialize the "Idx"
{
    static constexpr int value = Head;
};

template <size_t Idx, int Head, int... Tail>
struct Get<Idx, Vector<Head, Tail...>>
{
    static_assert(Idx > 0, "Out of Vector bound");
    static constexpr int value = Get<Idx - 1, Vector<Tail...>>::value;
};

template <size_t Pos, int Val, typename Vec>
struct Insert;

template <size_t Pos, int Val, typename Vec>
using InsertT = typename Insert<Pos, Val, Vec>::type;

template <int Val, int... Elems>
struct Insert<0, Val, Vector<Elems...>> // partial specialize the "Pos"
{
    using type = Vector<Val, Elems...>;
};

template <size_t Pos, int Val, int Head, int... Tail>
struct Insert<Pos, Val, Vector<Head, Tail...>>
{
    using type = PrependT<Head, InsertT<Pos - 1, Val, Vector<Tail...>>>; // push an element in the front of the vector
};

int main()
{
    // test Vector
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Vector<1, 2>, Vector<1, 2>>);

    // test Prepend
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Prepend<1, Vector<2, 3>>::type, Vector<1, 2, 3>>);

    // test Get
    static_assert(Get<0, Vector<0, 1, 2>>::value == 0);
    static_assert(Get<1, Vector<0, 1, 2>>::value == 1);
    static_assert(Get<2, Vector<0, 1, 2>>::value == 2);

    // test Insert
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert<0, 3, Vector<4, 5, 6>>::type, Vector<3, 4, 5, 6>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert<1, 3, Vector<4, 5, 6>>::type, Vector<4, 3, 5, 6>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert<2, 3, Vector<4, 5, 6>>::type, Vector<4, 5, 3, 6>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert<3, 3, Vector<4, 5, 6>>::type, Vector<4, 5, 6, 3>>);
}
```

In my opinion, the partial specialization in both operations is the same. **Why does one compile successfully while the other fails?**

Comment: How is `PrependT` defined? Shouldn't `Idx` be the same type as `Pos`?

Comment: Code is a bit weird, inasmuch as it doesn't seem to actually _do_ anything.  Shouldn't `Get` and `Insert` be _function_ templates?

Comment: Make it `template <size_t Val, int... Elems> struct Insert<0, Val, Vector<Elems...>>` (note no `Pos` in the list of template parameters). As written, `Pos` cannot be deduced. This is the same as the first specialization of `Get`, wherein you omitted `Idx`

Comment: @Bob__
I put the full code below the "update:" including the definition of the 'PrependT'.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I have modified the code, but it still does not work.  All the code is placed below the "update".

Comment: Is C++20 an option (see e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/z9qv18cvK) or are you stuck with `std::enable_if`?

Comment: Ah. It's because neither specialization is more specialized than the other. `Insert<0, ...`> is more specialized on the first argument, the other is more specialized on the `Vector<...>` type argument.

Comment: Can be salvaged by adding another specialization. [Like this](https://godbolt.org/z/jP8c91KqG)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Igor Tandetnik, the reason why the origin code doesn't work is `Insert<0, Val, Vector<Elems...>>` is more specialized on the first argument than `Insert<Pos, Val, Vector<Head, Tail...>>`, but the `Vector<Elems...>` is less specialized than the `Vector<Head, Tail...>`. **Thus, neither specialization is more specialized than the other**.

Based on the above facts, Igor Tandetnik proposes the following solution. There are two main modifications to this solution.On the one hand, the `Vector<Elems...>` is changed into `Vector<Head, Tail...>` so that the `Insert<0, Val, Vector<Elems...>>` and `Insert<Pos, Val, Vector<Head, Tail...>>` are only diff in `Pos`. On the other hand, a specialization is added to process the situation of adding `Val` to empty `Vector` at `Pos=0`.

```
template <size_t Pos, int Val, typename Vec>
struct Insert;

template <size_t Pos, int Val, typename Vec>
using InsertT = typename Insert<Pos, Val, Vec>::type;

template <int Val>
struct Insert<0, Val, Vector<>> // Insert element at 0 into an empty vector.
{
    using type = Vector<Val>;
};

template <int Val, int Head, int... Tail>
struct Insert<0, Val, Vector<Head, Tail...>>  // Insert element at 0 into non-empty vector.
{
    using type = Vector<Val, Head, Tail...>;
};

template <size_t Pos, int Val, int Head, int... Tail>
struct Insert<Pos, Val, Vector<Head, Tail...>>
{
    using type = PrependT<Head, InsertT<Pos - 1, Val, Vector<Tail...>>>; // push an element in the front of the vector
};
```

And @Bob__ gives another solution based on C++20 by using `requires`. The `requires` describes the constraints on the `Pos` argument.

```
template <size_t Pos, int Val, typename Vec>
struct Insert;

template <size_t Pos, int Val, typename Vec>
using InsertT = typename Insert<Pos, Val, Vec>::type;

template <int Val, int... Elems>
struct Insert<0ull, Val, Vector<Elems...>> // partial specialize the "Pos"
{
    using type = Vector<Val, Elems...>;
};

template <size_t Pos, int Val, int Head, int... Tail>
  requires (Pos > 0)                                       // <-----
struct Insert<Pos, Val, Vector<Head, Tail...>>
{
    using type = PrependT<Head, InsertT<Pos - 1, Val, Vector<Tail...>>>; // push an element in the front of the vector
};
```